# add_menu_page doesn't add any pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't figure out why my code doesn't work. I'm developing a plug-in in wordpress and I want it to have a page in the admin panel. I tried this code put it didn't brought me far.

```html
<?php 

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_menu() {
    echo '<h1>test</h1>';
 add_menu_page(  'Overzicht producten', 
                    'Overzicht top', 
                    'manage_options', 
                    'overzichtproducten/index.php', 
                    'overzicht_admin_page' , 
                    null, 
                    6);

}

function overzicht_admin_page(){
    echo "test";
 ?> 
 <div class="wrap">
  <h2>Welcome To My Plugin</h2>
 </div>
<?php
}

?>
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code works fine. When you say it isn't working, what exactly is the problem you are having? e.g. does the option not appear in the admin menu? Does it not open a page? Do you get an error? etc

Comment: Hey! It doesn't do anything. I save the code in the plug-in map and when i reload the page there is no menu item added. So there doesn't even appear a menu item. I do not get any errors.

Comment: What do you mean the "plug-in map"? If you add it directly into the main plugin file it works. e.g. if your plugin is called myplugin, then add it to the myplugin.php file.

Comment: I made a map in the plug-in file from wordpress named overzichtproducten. In that file I saved the php file above. I can even edit it in wordpress plug-in editor!

Comment: Do you have a clue? @FluffyKitten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the code above works but only in the same file as where you put in the name of your plug-in.

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Overzicht producten
Description: Een aansluiting op Woocommerce als overzicht van producten.
Author: Nynke van de Nadort
Version: 1.0
Author URI: none
Text Domain: Nynke van de Nadort
*/ 

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_menu() {
 add_menu_page(  'Overzicht producten', 
                    'Overzicht top', 
                    'manage_options', 
                    'overzichtproducten/index.php', 
                    'overzicht_admin_page' , 
                    null, 
                    10);

}

function overzicht_admin_page(){
 ?> 
 <div class="wrap">
  <h2>Welcome To My Plugin</h2>
 </div>
<?php
} 

 
?>
```